# How to non-interactively add a Splunk forwarder?

Tags: splunk

I wish to create a script for setting up forwarding to a splunk server. Here's what I have so far:

`./splunk add forward-server SPLUNK-IP-ADDRESS:SPLUNK-PORT`

However, it asks for my credentials. How can I non-interactively pass credentials to splunk and setup the forwarder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `splunk login` command to pass your credentials to the Splunk server:

```
./splunk login -auth 'admin:mypassword'
./splunk add forward-server SPLUNK-IP-ADDRESS:SPLUNK-PORT
```

Comment: of course - doing this means the username and password are in your command history